# how to enscape spring data jpa when the query is complex?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have a lot of report to export, and the datas are queryed by spring data jpa,but when i coding, it was disgusting.
some code:

```
public Object getReportBySupplier(ReportSupplierSearch reportSearch) {
        // 查询统计数据
        StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer("SELECT ifnull(sum(apply_money), 0) money_count, count(1) itemCount FROM cash WHERE confirm_status = 2 ");
        sql.append("and supplier_id = " + reportSearch.getSupplierId());
        String start = null;
        String end = null;
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(reportSearch.getStime())) {
            start = reportSearch.getStime() + " 00:00:00";
            sql.append(" and paying_time >= " + "'" + start + "'");
        }
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(reportSearch.getEtime())) {
            end = reportSearch.getEtime() + " 23:59:59";
            sql.append(" and paying_time <= " + "'" + end + "'");
        }
        sql.append(" UNION ALL");
        sql.append(" SELECT ifnull((sum(t1.pay_money)), 0) money_count, count(1) itemCount FROM pay_info t1 ");
        sql.append(" where t1.supplier_id =" + reportSearch.getSupplierId());
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(reportSearch.getStime())) {
            sql.append(" and pay_time >= " + "'" + start + "'");
        }
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(reportSearch.getEtime())) {
            sql.append(" and pay_time <= " + "'" + end + "'");
        }
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql.toString());
        List result = query.getResultList();
        return assembleReportBean(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make use of @query annotation or queryexecuterdsl. 
This will help you to create query in manageable form.

Comment: but the query is always dynamic.

Comment: Using above approach you can make query dynamic. Use Naming Parameter query to use result of sub query query(Dynamic Result) into main query.
Still if this method didn't fulfil your needs then you can provide your own methods and its implementation like above.